# Navigation to hashtag using jQuery - show / hide content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, hyperlink

I have a page, which has 3 placeholders with text. These are all hidden on page_load, and jQuery sets them to visible depending on whether there is a hashtag or not.

I want to use inline linking using hashtags like `<a href="#references"></a>`. Depending on the hashtag, I want to show/hide other content.

It would be easy to get to work using querystrings, but unfortunately, that will give very bad search engine optimization in my case.

I got a solution working, but there is one major problem. When the user clicks my menu in the top, which appends the hashtag, it goes to the link, but my jQuery is first run on the second click. The following happens:

1. We are on URL http://www.domain.com
2. The user clicks on my menu and the url is http://www.domain.com#info , but nothing changed in the markup
3. The user clicks the menu the second time, url is same, but now the markup changes

**My jQuery script:**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            updateview();
        });

        function updateview() {
            if (document.location.hash.search('calculator') !== -1) {
                $("#ContentContainer").hide();
                $("#VideoPnl").hide();
                $("#CalculatorPnl").show();
            }
            else if (document.location.hash.search('video') !== -1) {
                $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
                $("#VideoPnl").show();
                $("#ContentContainer").hide();
            } else {
                $("#ContentContainer").show();
                $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
                $("#VideoPnl").hide();
            }
        }
```

**My menu**

Every menu point at my menu have the following JavaScript added, which I hoped would change the screen when clicking, but this one first works the second time:

```
menu.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:updateview()");
```

**My markup in ASP.NET:**

```
   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ContentContainer" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ContentPlaceholder"></asp:Literal>

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="CalculatorPnl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CalculatorHeadlineLtl"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CalculatorPlaceholder"></asp:Literal>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="VideoPnl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="VideoHeadlineLtl"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="VideoPlaceholder"></asp:Literal>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateview` is called from within the click handler. When the `updateview` function executes for the first time, the url has no hash. The hash gets appended to the url after all click handlers have been executed. To demostate that, rewrite your `updateview` as follows:

```
function updateview(evt) {
    if (evt && evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    if (document.location.hash.search('calculator') !== -1) {
        $("#ContentContainer").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").hide();
        $("#CalculatorPnl").show();
    }
    else if (document.location.hash.search('video') !== -1) {
        $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").show();
        $("#ContentContainer").hide();
    } else {
        $("#ContentContainer").show();
        $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").hide();
    }
}
```

The first 5 lines prevent the event from doing its default action, which is to follow the link and append the hash to the url. Now if you click the menu, nothing will happen, irrespective of how many times you click. Also, with your earlier code, the second time if you were to click on some other menu item, you would still have seen the div for the previous menu item.

Now that it's clear why the problem is happening, the solution I can think of is:
   - get the hash using the event object
   - display the correct div
   - let the event bubble up

You haven't shown the code for you menu, so I am assuming it's a `ul` where each `li` contains an `a` tag which has the required href set. I am also assuming that the click handler is added to each anchor tag.

Code for the same:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        updateview(hash);
    });

function updateview(hash) {

    if (!hash) {
        hash = document.location.hash;
    }

    if (hash.search('calculator') !== -1) {
        $("#ContentContainer").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").hide();
        $("#CalculatorPnl").show();
    }
    else if (hash.search('video') !== -1) {
        $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").show();
        $("#ContentContainer").hide();
    } else {
        $("#ContentContainer").show();
        $("#CalculatorPnl").hide();
        $("#VideoPnl").hide();
    }
}

function menuClick(evt) {
    if (!evt) {
        evt = window.event;
    }

    var target = (evt.currentTarget) ? evt.currentTarget : evt.srcElement,
        hash = target.getAttribute('href');

    updateview(hash);
}
```

The changes are, `updateview` accepts the hash as a parameter. In dom ready, this parameter is provided its value from `document.location.hash`. In the click handler, it gets its value from the `href` of the `anchor` tag that was clicked. `menuClick` is the click handler that you need to bind to each `anchor` tag in your menu.

I don't code in WebForms, so I can't help you with the exact semantics. I hope you understand enough of the cause of the problem and my intended solution.

Comment: That's one beast of an answer, which deserves a lot of up-votes. Thanks! :-)